# How to use text between the tags in a svelte component?

Tags: components, svelte

Let's say I have two components:

Bold1.svelte:

```
<script>
    external let t="";
</script>
<b>{t}</b}
```

Usage:

```
<Bold1 t="my text 1" />
```

Works like expected.

Bold2.svelte:

```
<script>    
</script>
<b>???</b>
```

Usage:

```
<Bold2>
    my text 2
</Bold2>
```

What do I have to write instead of ??? to get a bold `my text 2`? I have tried `<b>{this}</b>`, but without success.

Comment: Use: <b><slot /></b>

Comment: Yes, I was looking for <slot/>. Now I want to clarify how to assign the contents of <slot/> to a variable. Something like let x = $$slots; I know this is not the answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the slot content.

App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Child from './Child.svelte';
</script>

<Child>Hi</Child>
```

Child.svelte

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    let thisObj;
    let text = '';
    
    onMount(() => {
        text = thisObj.textContent;
    });
</script>

<div bind:this={thisObj}>
    <slot />
</div>

<h3>
    Slot content-1: {text}
</h3>
```

Comment: Great! This example should be included in the Svelte tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass HTML and have it render as HTML?
If var `t` has HTML, you can render it like this:
`{@html t}`

https://svelte.dev/docs

Just watch out for XSS risk.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was looking for <slot/>. Thanks anyway!